# How to avoid the previous values in php array overridden by the later ones?

Tags: php, arrays

How to avoid `34 overridden by 124` in the following `PHP` code? I just want to keep the `34` and `124` both.

```
$arr = array(12, 34, "df"=>43, "1"=>124, 65);
$num = count($arr);
reset($arr);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $num; ++$i) {
    echo 'The Current Position：' . key($arr);
    echo '<br />';
    echo 'The Current Value：'. current($arr);
    next($arr);
    echo '<br />';
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Just let PHP do the indexing.

Comment: you can remove the keys from the array.

Comment: @Rizier123 If I want to keep "1" as the key of 124, how to deal with it?

Comment: In the definition itself you can't do anything about it. You would have to check if the key already exist, before you overwrite it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP will always treat all numeric keys as integers even if they are inside string variables or quotes.

The following can make it quite apparent:

```
<?php

$arr = [1 => 'hi', '2' => 'bye', 'a1' => 'hiha'];

var_export($arr);
```

The solution is to prefix the values that you don't want indexed as integers with a letter.

Note that mixing indexed and associative arrays indicates a serious lack of organization that you will regret later, if you don't already.

Answer (score 1):

> Your array indexing is not valid.

You need to design an array with unique keys, let `PHP` do the indexing. you can change the index "1" with "one" for unique key.

If you `print_r` your array then you must see the result like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 124
    [df] => 43
    [2] => 65
)
```

So don't make an array with duplicate key, you might loss data.

```
$arr = array(12, 34, "df" => 43, "one" => 124, 65);
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    echo $key." - ".$val."<br/>";
}
```

Result:

```
key - value
0   - 12
1   - 34
df  - 43
one - 124
2   - 65
```